# Creating yum repo

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I followed this [link](http://www.how2centos.com/creating-a-local-yum-repository-on-centos-5x/) on how to create my own yum repository for base install and update purposes. If you notice, why would I need a 5 folder on top of 5.4? My installation at the moment is all 5.4, so when I ran "yum update" it wanted to go to http://domain.com/5/... instead of picking up the 5.4 directory. Is 5 basically 5.4 w/ the most updated packages for that tree? meaning, if 5.5 comes out, 5 would be the latest and greatest and if I wanted to track 5.4, I would still need a 5.4 folder to track changes with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, within `5`, there are symlinks to the latest version of CentOS 5.  With older versions, the main number directory was the symlink.

With my local repo, I follow this convention.  That way, I can rsync the latest version without having to manually update all my server's yum.conf when a new version is released.

Updates to the distribution are included within `5/updates`.

Comment: So rsyncing 5.4 and 5 is basically the same thing (at the moment until new version is out)? If i follow the site I found the tutorial on, he's rsyncing both 5 and 5.4, but until a new version of 5.x comes out, having to rsync two diff repo is pointless, no?

Comment: So with an older version of RHEL/Centos, I'll have to substitute $releasever with "4.3" or "4.5" if 4.8 is the latest?

Comment: I would sync 5, create a complete copy as "5.4," and resync updates to 5.  When 5.5 comes out, you would have a manual step of creating a copy of 5 as 5.5.  But, if you don't have a requirement of keeping 5.4 around, you could just rsync to latest which would automatically change with new releases.